# Wordplay: I O _________ O A!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

The word in the blank is a metal or a medal.

This is a puzzle I thought of and haven't seen anywhere. Hopefully, it is up to the standards of this site.

Answer (score 33):

Is it...

> **Silver** (both a metal and a medal)

Because...

> Then the title sounds like [**"Hi-yo, Silver, away!"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Ranger), the catchphrase that the Lone Ranger shouted to his horse Silver. :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy pls rot13 not reverse :| (type as: `rot13(<rot13'd text here>)`)

Comment: And that is rot13(obgu n zrgny (Nt) naq n zrqny (2aq))